# How do you display a background image to full screen from a file java?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to view the image of background to full screen.  How can I do it?  I want to set my **TableLayout* full screen from Java code.

```
tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
tableLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna);
```

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: i want to set my tablelayout full screen from java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
tableLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

try the above to code to set tablelayout full screen